# How to detect the already selected mailbox using IMAP commands?

Tags: imap

Is there any IMAP command, which can help to identify the currently selected mailbox.

Use case:
Suppose there is a proxy server which is caching the IMAP connection, when the clients connect , clients need not waste time selecting the mailbox if its already selected.

Comment: I don't believe so.  IMAP has a strictly defined state machine, and the client needs to keep track of the state.  Going from NON-AUTHENTICATED to SELECTED is an invalid state transition.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the RFC3501's state machine, as Max said. There is no way you could "end up" already selected into any mailbox. If something like that happened, the IMAP proxy would be hopelessly broken and there would be no sane way of using it.

See the [IMAP state machine from RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-15). Within the IMAP protocol, after the connection is established, the state can only ever be one of "authenticated", "unauthenticated" and "logout". At no time it is possible to enter the selected state directly.

If you add an "IMAP proxy" to the picture, either it *cannot* cache the IMAP connections in this way, or you cannot talk IMAP to your proxy. While there could easily be some protocol inspired by IMAP which you can use here, i.e. with a couple of extensions for doing exactly what you'd like to do, it would not be IMAP as defined by RFC3501 anymore.

Now, what is definitely possible is to have a proxy in front of your IMAP servers which would help with e.g. TLS connection overhead. However, if that is your setup, your IMAP proxy *must* make sure that no mailbox is selected at the time the connection is reused. You will also have to invent some reauthentication method as well, but that's outside of scope now.

For a little more technical background on why it is designed this way, be sure to read [how the `SELECT` command works](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.1). In IMAP, certain mailbox data are transfered during the `SELECT` processing, and these data are very important to ensure that both client and server share a well-synchronized view of the mailbox state. If your client suddenly jumped into the selected state, you would have to get these metadata in some other way (and note that this "other way" is explicitly forbidden, i.e. you [should not issue `STATUS` on the currently selected mailbox](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.10). With a reasonably modern IMAP server, i.e. one which supports [`CONDSTORE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4551) or [`QRESYNC`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5162) extensions, the requirements are even more important.

In general, the IMAP protocol does *not* benefit from proxies in the way most people expect it to do. If you actually need to use one, perhaps you can share more information on what leads you to this conclusion.

Comment: Hope you didn't get my question. I will elaborate, say an IMAP proxy can cache a connection till 5 minutes. So the client first connects to the proxy, the proxy opens the connection, then login and selects inbox.  Now within 5 minutes if the same client connects to proxy it need not open the connection again, because the connection is in Authenticated and selected state. This saves few seconds(10 - 30 sec). The only problem arises here is that when the second time the client connects it doesn't know what mailbox is selected. This is how we end up in a "already selected" state.

Comment: I have added much more details to my reply; hope you will find it clearer now.